# The calculation of Gateaux derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

How to calculate the Gateaux derivative of the following functional especially when $p$ is not a integer where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set ?

$I(u)=\int_{\Omega} |u|^p dx$

Besides, how to prove that $I(u)$ is Frechet differentiable?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3274845/568204) for how to calculate the Gateaux derivative (apart from a factor of $p$). To prove Frechet differentiability you will have to specify where your functions $u$ are coming from (and usually by looking at the explicit formula for the Gateaux derivative, if you can prove it is continuous, then you can deduce that in fact $I$ is continuously differentiable, so this is the simplest way, otherwise you have to resort to the definitions directly... which isn't always nice).

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!!